# Parse out negative scientific form numbers joined in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some data that I would like to read into a numpy array. The data is in string format. One row is of the form

```
' 0.600759893E-02 0.000000000E+00-0.112325850E-02 0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00'
```

I would like to parse the string into five separate numbers. This is straightforward if there is a space between all numbers. Unfortunately it is harder in the case where the number is negative, since there is no space between the negative number and the preceding number. The minus signs don't just appear in front of the negative numbers. Sometimes, the exponent is negative, as shown in the case above for the first number. Any fast ways to parse a row like the one above into five separate numbers?

Here is a MWE of the code I currently have

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv')
dim1 = 5
geometryparameters = np.zeros(dim1,dtype=float)

c=data1.iloc[1,0] # Just taking the first row, which is in string format
csplit = c.split(" ") # Splitting the string into parts
for it1 in np.arange(dim1):
    geometryparameters[it1] = float(csplit[it1]) # converting the string into float
```

The above code fails in some cases because of minus sign issue mentioned above.

Comment: It is always best to include the code that you tried and its output.  Otherwise people might interpret this as looking for someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot have the input fixed, since the number always ends by `E+/-xx`, you could insert a space when you encounter this pattern (using regex), then split & convert to float:

```
import re

s = ' 0.600759893E-02 0.000000000E+00-0.112325850E-02 0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00'

result = [float(x) for x in re.sub("(E[+\-]\d\d)",r"\1 ",s).split()]

print(result)
```

(searches for `E<sign> and 2 digits` with capture and replaces by the same thing (`\1`) plus space.

Yields:

```
[0.00600759893, 0.0, -0.0011232585, 0.0, 0.0]
```

EDIT: even faster with only regexes and `findall`, no `str.split`:

```
result = [float(x) for x in re.findall(r"\b.*?E[+\-]\d\d",s)]
```

looks for a word (note the word boundary on the left, non-greedy or it would match more than 1 number), and the exponent expression on the right.

Comment: Adding a short explanation on the role of `"\1 "` will make this answer perfect.

Comment: @PhillipD edited. But the variant with `re.findall` is IMHO better.

Answer (score 2):

From your information, each number field is exactly 16 characters long.  Therefore each line is 80 characters long.

So for each line, x will be the list of the 5 numbers:

```
x = [float(line[n:n+16]) for n in range(0,80,16)]
```